# duplicate column name error in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I get an error of dupicate column name if fromm my query and dont know how to solve my query is

```
SELECT distinct(courseid+senderid+recipientid) as diskey,
       mess.id,
       User.firstName as recipientName,
       Course.name,
       senderid,
       recipientid,
       courseid,
       message,
       mess.status,
       mess.createdOn 
FROM 
(
    SELECT * 
    from Message,User,Course 
    where Message.recipientid=User.id 
        and Message.courseid=Course.id 
    order by Message.createdOn DESC
) as mess,
     User,
     Course 
WHERE senderid ='3' 
      OR recipientid='3' 
GROUP BY diskey;
```

can any one heplp

Comment: Table schemas would be helpful.

Comment: and the result you are getting

Comment: @BrunoVieira duplicate column name

Comment: The error message usually includes the exact position of the error. So please attach the very message you get, while executing this query.

Comment: My suggestion would be to review SQL JOIN syntax - here is a [great visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: @bluefeet I don't like comma joins either, but they're valid syntax anyways ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak might be valid, but they are joining on each table multiple times. I doubt that is the intention

Comment: @bluefeet good point - comma joins easily lead to missing join conditions.

Comment: Oh that's right @JanDvorak he isn't get any result other than Duplicate Column Name

Comment: @ Sirko the error displayed is      Duplicate column name 'id'

Answer (score 7):

To avoid duplication prefix the column name with its table as follows:

```
tab_name.col_name
```

Comment: +1 Without more details from the asker, anything above this would be guessing

Comment: my table structure is like  Message | CREATE TABLE `Message` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `courseid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `senderid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `recipientid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `createdOn` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `fileName` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

Answer (score 0):

Try writing all column names attach with their respective table names:

Column names without table name attached in your query:
`… senderid,recipientid,courseid,message …`

You should also write above as you are writing these in your query:
`… mess.id,User.firstName …`

Hope this will solve the error.

Comment: coloumn name attach with table names doesnt work it still shows same error

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
WHERE senderid ='3' 
  OR recipientid='3'
```

with

```
HAVING senderid ='3' 
  OR recipientid='3'
```

Happy Coding !

Answer (score 0):

to avoid duplication write query as below using prefix(tableName).columnname:

```
select id, name1,name2 from(
select table1.id,table1.name as name1, table2.name as name2 from
table1
innerjoin table2 on table1.id=table2.table1_id
)group by id
```